# How can i check my script is working fine in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter. I did my first script in JMeter.

My scenario is: clicking a button, i.e. after login, click that button. Thats it. Upto this i have recorded for my script using JMeter.

When i run for single user, it gives proper output for any different user. But when i run with concurrent users (2 or more users with User Parameters pre-processor), it shows error in clicking that button.
I have used View Results Tree as listener to see the results.

In sometimes, it does not show error. So i can't identify the exact reason, why it fails.
Can you please anyone can guide me regarding this?

I am completely new to this JMeter.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Which error jMeter reports in 'view results tree'? Have you checked what your application server says in its log when that error occurs? I don't think this error is caused by jMeter, since this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
In 'View Results Tree', I got Server Error in Application(in Response Data).
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

What can we do for this as a tester?

Please reply.

Comment: Please answer the second question. That message tells you only that the problem is not at jMeter side, but your application or server.

Comment: Sorry. I dont know where can we see a log file. Please tell me that. Is it a .jtl file or other?

Comment: How your application URL looks like?

Comment: OK, so who responds to your requests on that IP address (on the port you're using)? That's server (like Tomcat, Jetty, Resin, Glassfish, BEA, Websphere, jBoss, ...) . And it "usually" has a log file (called SystemOut.log or similar).

Comment: Sorry I am not sure about that:( Simply i am running using JMeter. Not sure about Config details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 internal server error indicates jmeter is making the connection to your server and your server is having difficulty processing the request. You should probably look at your server log files to see if there are any errors or exceptions (apache/jetty/etc log file).

Additionally, when you DO actually have an issue with jmeter and you can't seem to figure out what is going on from your listener output, you can view the jmeter.log file created in the directory when jmeter is run from. This usually gives more detailed information regarding failures in jmeter.